# Why won't my a:hover work and my <a> tag won't go to link on click?

Tags: html, css

I have been writing a website that is a bunch of different sections on top of one another. The div with the class `class="concertDiv"` is the container of one section. I'm trying to have an album cover on the left side of this section and on the right side I want three rows of text all clickable to go to a link. I'm trying to make these three `<a>` tags, placed one on top of another, change color on hover and go to https://google.com on click, both of these things aren't working.

**This is my HTML/CSS code for the project:**

```css
a.concertDesc {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #f65026;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

a.concertDesc: hover {
  color: blue;
}

#albumCover {
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.concertElement {
  display: inline;
}

.concertDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

@media (max-width: 590px) {
  p.concertDesc {
    white-space: pre-line;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #albumCover {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="concertDiv">

  <img id="albumCover" class="concertElement" src="assets/albumCover.jpg" />

  <div class="concertElement" style="padding-left: 15px;">

    <a class="concertDesc" href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="font-size: 225%;">Click 1</a>

    <a class="concertDesc" href="https://google.com" style="font-size: 150%;">Click 2</a>
    <a class="concertDesc" href="https://google.com" style="font-size: 140%;">Click 3</a>

  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You have a syntax error, it should be `:hover`, not `: hover`.

Comment: You also have `pointer-events: none;` which will prevent clicks.

Comment: You're making the links properly. It must be something like Jack's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) set to `none` you prevent `touch` and `click` to be effective.

> The pointer-events CSS property sets under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of pointer events.

The whitespace in `a.concertDesc: hover` doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so problem one:
    `a.concert.Desc: hover` shouldn't have this white space here
                              ^
                           here


problem two:

remove the `pointer-events: none;` 
style because that prevents the link from working.

curious: did you copy and paste this?